# How do I have multiple chip autocomplete on the same page using Angular material 7.1.1?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-material-7

I'm using Angular 6 with Angular material 7.1.1
And i'm trying to use chip with auto complete. But the problem is that when i select one of the option, that gets applied to all the chips with autocomplete.

```
`<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
      [selectable]="selectable"
      [removable]="removable"
      (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
      placeholder="New fruit..."
      #fruitInput
      [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto1"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
      {{fruit}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>`
```

How do i get it to apply only to the particular input field?

Comment: The above snippet is the angular material example. What changes should be made to the above snippet to have another chip autocomplete?

Comment: have a look at:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-465vnw-umqv76

Comment: Is that you require?

Comment: Yes, @PrashantPimpale this is what i need, but with autocomplete.
For some reason it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that with this https://stackblitz.com/angular/bxoneaokmgg?file=app%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts
I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Have implemented have a look:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9nqcxf

Comment: Thanks a lot @PrashantPimpale this was what i wanted. thanks! :)

Comment: Have added an answer please check

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples     (Chips Autocomplete)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to change the id of the mat-chip-list.

So on your first you set the id

`<mat-chip-list #chipList>`

and on your second you set the id

`<mat-chip-list #chipList2>`

Then you set

`[matChipInputFor]="chipList"`

and `[matChipInputFor]="chipList2"`

Now it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a different list for each Chip list and also two different attribute for `[matAutocomplete]`

HTML Code:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
            {{fruit}}
            <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
        <input
      placeholder="New fruit..."
      #fruitInput
      [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
      {{fruit}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

<h2>Second Chips List</h2>

<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let fruit of fruits1"
      [selectable]="selectable"
      [removable]="removable"
      (removed)="remove1(fruit)">
      {{fruit}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
      placeholder="New fruit..."
      #fruitInput1
      [formControl]="fruitCtrl1"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto1"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add1($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected1($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
      {{fruit}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

[A Working StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9nqcxf)

Comment: Is there any way to make it generic function?

Comment: @Shivam yes, but need to think on it